# In the alternate timeline of "Yesterday's Enterprise", had Data and Tasha Yar "done it"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

In the first season episode "The Naked Now", Tahsa Yar and Data have an (ahem) intimate moment.  Although Tahsa expresses her desire to forget it at the end of that episode, other episodes refer to this special relationship between these characters ("Skin of Evil", "The Measure of a Man", "The Most Toys").

In the episode "Yesterday's Enterprise", Tasha reappears in an alternate timeline.  Clearly this means that her death in "Skin of Evil" never happened.  *But did they still have the intimate affair of "The Naked Now"?*

Quotes by her daughter Sela, novelizations, and expanded-universe materials are fair game.

Not really related:

- [Did Data and Tasha Yar's 'relationship' continue after the polywater incident?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22213)
- [Why wasn't there more timeline divergence in "Yesterday's Enterprise" than what we observed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38604)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that the events of "The Naked Now" happened at all, given how the timeline was altered.

It was a very specific set of events that brought on that intimate moment between the two, namely having their minds altered by the Psi 2000 virus. Given the effect it had on the crew of the Tsiolkovsky, one can only wonder if Tasha's sudden attraction to Data was a reveal of something she truly felt or a sudden impulse caused by the effect of the virus.

But, in the altered timeline, with the Federation slowly losing the war with the Klingons, it's quite improbable that the Tsolkiovski was sent to investigate the star and the Enterprise sent after them when they failed to report.

As far as I remember, Sela only mentioned her mother having a relation with her Romulan father, and, in the episode, Tasha fell in love with Lieutenant Castillo, the Helmsman of the Enterprise-C.

I do not remember any mention of this intimate moment happening in the alternate timeline in any of the EU material that I read.